# Is it possible to disable automatic x-axis zooming on a specific series in Highcharts?

Tags: javascript, elasticsearch, highcharts, zooming, flags

I've been looking all over but not found any answers for this.

So a bit of background. I've created an in-house analytics system for the company I work for off the back of highcharts. The analytics data is pulled from a nosql database via elasticsearch queries. The returned information is converted into formats suitable for different highcharts graphs. The range and interval of the data is user defined and plumbed into the query, manipulating that query behind the scenes to say "now-1d" to "now" or "now-1w" etc for the range of data required.

So i'm trying to add a flag series to my system. The flags are based on a number of comments pulled from the same database. The problem is that, whilst I can remove the flag series from the main legend area, the older flags expand the graph out of recognition ([Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E4prh.png))
The range of the data is user defined, like I said, but in a different format to one supported in javascript. This means I cant just force the min and max of the x-axis.... because I don't know (or even care) about what they are in my system.

Im wondering if there is any way to force a specific series to not scale the x-axis of the graph and be ignored in that regard.

Thanks

Comment: There is no out-of-the-box solution included in Highcharts. But if the user is selecting the range of the data to display, then there shouldn't be any reason you can't apply that to the chart, or filter the out-of-range data points out. Perhaps if you can give more detail...

Comment: I don't think that it is a way to force series to not scale the x-axis. The main idea of series is to show it in your chart. It should be really simple to filter your data and remove all of points that are far away from your different series. You may also use setExtremes() method for showing only the data between min and max you would like to. The best would be if you will be able to show live example of your chart.